# Merging data from one spreadsheet into another based on two parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I have two spreadsheets. In the first I have a piece of data that I want to carry into the second. The trick is in the second Spreadsheet, I have the common data point in potentially 2 columns. So for Example:

Sheet 1:

| Size | Company Name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Small | ABC Inc. | 1 |
| Medium | XYZ Inc. | 2 |
| Large | DEF Inc. | 3 |

Sheet 2:

| ID_1 | Company Name_1 | ID_2 | Company Name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC Inc. | 3 | DEF Inc. |
| 2 | XYZ Inc. | 4 | Acme |

So based on the ID, I would like to merge the `Sheet 1` "Size" data and associate it with the company, so that Table 3 would look like this:

| ID_1 | Company Name_1 | Size | ID_2 | Company Name_2 | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC Inc. | Small | 3 | DEF Inc. | Large |
| 2 | XYZ Inc. | Medium | 4 | Acme |  |

I'm no expert on this, and have tried some basic joins, but it hasn't worked out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `ID_1` / `ID_2` values of `df2` to the same `ID` value of `df1` and get the `size` from `df1`.  Then, use [`.insert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to insert the columns at the required position:

Assuming `Sheet 1` / `Sheet 2` dataframes are called `df1` / `df2` respectively:

```
df2.insert(2, 'Size_1', df2['ID_1'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Size']))
df2.insert(5, 'Size_2', df2['ID_2'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Size']))
```

Result:

```
print(df2)


   ID_1 Company Name_1  Size_1  ID_2 Company Name_2 Size_2
0     1       ABC Inc.   Small     3       DEF Inc.  Large
1     2       XYZ Inc.  Medium     4           Acme    NaN
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution, however I am getting an Invalid Index Error. My datasets have many duplicate Companies, could this be the reason the .map() method is not working? I do not want to deduplicate though

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  Even duplicate `ID` in `sheet 1` ?  In that case, need other solution then.

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  If `sheet 1` has duplicate entries on `ID`, how can we depend on it to get the `Size` ?   Can we assume we can get for example, the first or last entries of the dups ?  If yes, we have work-around solution for it.

Comment: I think I am looking for functionality to a VLOOKUP. There is only one ID related to the Company, however because my data is a list of transactions, you can have the same ID/Company combinations appear many times

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  If there is only one ID for a company in `df1` / `Sheet 1`, there should be no problem for the `.map()` function even though `df2` / `Sheet 2` has multiple `ID` entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, I have built two dataframes `df_1` with Sheet1's data and `df_2` with Sheet2's data. I have used [Pandas.DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) method in order to set `ID` column as the index:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
  columns=['Size', 'Company Name', 'ID'], 
  data=[['Small',   'ABC Inc.', 1],
        ['Medium',  'XYZ Inc.', 2],
        ['Large',   'DEF Inc.', 3]])
df_1.set_index('ID', inplace=True) #Set ID as index.
```

Then, I used [Pandas.Dataframe.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to make two dataframes: `df_join_1` and `df_join_2`. Finally, I have used [Pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) to make the final Dataframe.

```
df_join_1 = df_1.join(df_2.set_index('ID_1'), how='inner').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'ID_1'})
df_join_1 = df_join_1[['ID_1', 'Size', 'Company Name_1', 'ID_2', 'Company Name_2']] #Re-order columns
print(df_join_1)

df_join_2 = df_1.join(df_2.set_index('ID_2'), how='inner').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'ID_2'})
df_join_2 = df_join_2[['ID_1', 'Size', 'Company Name_1', 'ID_2', 'Company Name_2']] #Re-order columns
print(df_join_2)

df_output = pd.merge(df_join_1, df_join_2, on=['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'Company Name_1', 'Company Name_2'], how='outer', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
   ID_1 Size_1  Company Name_1  ID_2  Company Name_2  Size_2
0   1   Small       ABC Inc.      3      DEF Inc.      Large
1   2   Medium      XYZ Inc.      4        Acme        NaN
```